# Optimising a basic python method

Tags: python

I am trying to optimise the method I have stated below. The method `total_trade_amount` accepts three arguments `trade_queryset`, `tax`, `trade_fee`.

- `trade_queryset` is a list of objects returned by a Django model.
- `tax` is a boolean value.
- `trade_fee` is a boolean value.

```
def total_trade_amount(trade_queryset, tax, trade_fee):

    """
    - This method will just calculate the total trade amount for the provided trade_queryset.
    """

    total_amount = 0

    if queryset.exists():

        for trade in queryset:

            if tax = True and trade_fee = True:

                trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount

            elif tax = True and trade_fee = False:

                trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount - trade.trade_fee
            
            elif tax = False and trade_fee = True:

                trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount - trade.tax

            elif tax = False and trade_fee = False:

                trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount - trade.tax - trade.trade_fee
            
            total_amount = total_amount + trade_amount
    
    return total_amount
```

In the above method you can see I have too many `if` and `elif` conditions and it is inside a `for` loop. Now, for every object in `trade_queryset` those conditions will be evaluated and it doesn't make much sense because those conditions are not dependent on the individual object of `trade_queryset`.

Moreover, the evaluation of those conditions are dependent on the two variables i.e `tax` and `trade_fee` and the values for those conditions are provided as an argument to the method. A specific expression is evaluated for the condition which has been satisfied.

What I want to do is to evaluate these conditions just once and set the expression for all the items in `trade_queryset`.

Comment: Don't you think your conditions aren't right? When `trade_fee==False`, you're using it in your formula and when it's `True`, you don't. Same with `tax`

Comment: No the conditions are correct, `trade_transaction_amount`  comprises of `tax` and `trade_fee`. If the `tax=False` then I want to deduct it from the `trade_transaction_amount` and same goes for the `trade_fee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good start, by coercing the booleans tax and trade_fee into ints you can then just define a single function. This assumes that trade_fee and tax are always present on each trade.

```
def total_trade_amount(trade_queryset, tax, trade_fee):
    """ 
    - This method will just calculate the total trade amount for the provied trade_queryset.
    """

    total_amount = 0

    def calculate_trade_amount(trade):
        return trade.trade_transaction_amount - trade.trade_fee * (1 - trade_fee) - trade.tax * (1 - tax)

    if queryset.exists():
        for trade in trade_queryset:
            total_amount += calculate_trade_amount(trade)

    return total_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the two booleans only affects one part of the calculation. You could calculate them separately, and then sum up all the calculations:

```py
def total_trade_amount(trade_queryset, tax, trade_fee):

    """
    - This method will just calculate the total trade amount for the provied trade_queryset.
    """

    total_amount = 0

    if queryset.exists():

        for trade in queryset:
            trade_fee_amount = 0
            if not trade_fee:
                trade_fee_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount

            tax_amount = 0
            if not tax:
                tax_amount = trade.tax
            
            trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount - tax_amount - trade_fee_amount
            total_amount += trade_amount
    
    return total_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code.

[`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

```py
from itertools import chain


def total_trade_amount(trade_queryset, tax, trade_fee):
    """
    - This method will just calculate the total trade amount for the provied trade_queryset.
    """
    total_amount = 0
    if trade_queryset.exists():
        
        trade_values_list = list(chain(*trade_queryset.values_list("trade_transaction_amount", "trade_fee", "tax")))
        _trade_transaction_amount = sum(trade_values_list[::3])
        _trade_fee = sum(trade_values_list[1::3])
        _tax = sum(trade_values_list[2::3])

        if tax and trade_fee:

            total_amount = _trade_transaction_amount

        elif tax and not trade_fee:

            total_amount = _trade_transaction_amount - _trade_fee

        elif not tax and trade_fee:

            total_amount = _trade_transaction_amount - _tax

        elif not tax and not trade_fee:

            total_amount = _trade_transaction_amount - _tax - _trade_fee

    return total_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just subtracting values if the related boolean is False, so just do a check and subtract in that case.

Also I would leave the function early if `trade_queryset` doesn't exist instead of wrapping the remainder of the function in the block. (I'm assuming that `queryset` in your code is supposed to be the `trade_queryset` passed to the function)

Booleans can be evaluated with a simple if/if not without comparing them to True/False.

If the timing of this function is so critical that the two boolean checks within the loop are an issue, there are probably many other solutions at a higher level that would speed this process up, and removing those checks would be one of the last things to look at.

```
def total_trade_amount(trade_queryset, tax, trade_fee):
    if not trade_queryset.exists():
        return 0

    total_amount = 0
    for trade in trade_queryset:
        trade_amount = trade.trade_transaction_amount
        if not tax:
            trade_amount -= trade.tax
        if not trade_fee:
            trade_amount -= trade.trade_fee
        total_amount += trade_amount

    return total_amount
```